# Creating new source doesn't provide addFeature()

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I currently have a layer on my map and its source has a 'addFeature()' method defined. I created a function that is supposed to add new sources/layers to a layer group but the new sources do not have the same 'addFeature()' method. Here is my code:

```
function newLayer() {
var newsource = new ol.source.Vector({
    wrapX: false
});

var newVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: newsource,
    title: document.getElementById("layerName").value
});

vectorGroup.getLayers().getArray().push(newVector);
```

}

Would anyone know why my newsource variable does not have the addFeature method?

**EDIT**
Here's more of my code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [raster],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform(
            [-84.387314, 33.749249], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 15
    })
});
```

I have a button newLayer function that triggers when a user presses a button so they can create a new Layer.

```
function newLayer() {
    var newsource = new ol.source.Vector({
        wrapX: false
    });
    var newvector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: newsource,
        title: title,
        visible: true
    });

    map.addLayer(newvector);

    vector = newvector;
}
```

This is how I'm handling drawing to the map:

```
var draw; // global so we can remove it later
function addInteraction() {
    var value = typeSelect.value;
    if (value !== 'None') {
        draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: source,
            type: typeSelect.value
        });
        map.addInteraction(draw);
    }
}


/**
 * Handle change event.
 */
typeSelect.onchange = function() {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction();
};

addInteraction();
```

Here is where I listen for a drawing to be added to my vector's source:

```
vector.getSource().on('addfeature', function(event) {...};
```

I am able to create multiple layers but when I try to draw on different layers, it will only draw to this first layer. For example, if I have two layers, a and b, and choose to use b as my 'vector' variable, drawing on it will still push the feature to a instead of b.

Comment: Show us more code, we can't see where you try to add the features.

Comment: @dube I added more code to my post. Thank you!